# Mounting an RAID under Debian

Tags: debian, raid

I see the disk with `lsblk`, but in the output of `df -h`.
How do I mount the disks? If I remember correctly it is an ext4 stripe.

I tried `mount /dev/sda /folder`, it says *unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'*.

Comment: You have to use the resulting `md` device and not the `/dev/sd*` devices directly to mount the RAID volume. Look into `/proc/mdstat` to find the name of the RAID device to use for your `mount` command. That should be something like `/dev/md0 ... /dev/md127`. Also depending if you have partitioned the RAID device you have to use the partitions on that device or in case you have placed a LVM on top you should use the LVM for your mount command. Use `lvdisplay` to find LVMs.

Comment: @Thomas Why don't you make that an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the resulting `md` device and not the `/dev/sd*` devices directly to mount the RAID volume.

Look into */proc/mdstat* to find the name of the RAID device to use for your `mount` command. That should be something like `/dev/md0.../dev/md127`.
Also depending if you have partitioned the RAID device you have to use the partitions on that device or in case you have placed a LVM on top you should use the LVM for your mount command. Use `lvdisplay` to find LVMs.